# I want to open dropdown when I select value from any other dropdown specifically in iPad/iPhone.

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, knockout.js, drop-down-menu

I want to open one drop down on the change event occurs on other drop down. The following code snippet is working fine for browser but it is not working on iPhone/iPad in Hybrid Application.

Your help will be appreciated.Please check [Code snippet on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghanshyam253/esLws5px/2/)

```js
 
   
    function ViewModel(choices, choice) {
        
        this.choices = ko.observableArray();
        this.choice = ko.observable();
        this.changedropDown=function(data,event){
            console.log("inside changedropDown");
            this.bindDropDown(event);
        };
        this.bindDropDown= function(event){
            //event.stopPropagation();
            console.log("insdie bindDropDown");
            this.choices(choices);
            setTimeout(function() {
                       showDropDown("xyz");
                       }, 500);
        };
    };
    
    var showDropDown = function (id) {
        console.log("inside showDropDown");
        var dropdown = document.getElementById(id);
        var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        event.initMouseEvent('mousedown', true, true, window);
        dropdown.dispatchEvent(event);
    };
    var choices = [{ id: 1, name: "one" },
                   { id: 2, name: "two" },
                   { id: 3, name: "three" }];
                   ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(choices));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <select name="cars" data-bind="event:{change:function(data,event){changedropDown(data,event)}}">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="xyz" data-bind="options: choices, optionsText: 'name', value: choice"></select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is not working"? What *is* the behavior? What debugging have you done, and what error (if any) occurs? Does this happen only in the *hybrid* situation (and if so: what toolkit/framework?), or also if you open the snippet on such a device?

Comment: (In any case, I'd recommend against handling events like that; let KO handle bindings and use computed observables or subscriptions instead.)

Comment: I tried by removing the code of knockout.

Comment: When I open the code in XCODE simulator(iPhone/iPad) then it is not behaving as it is in browser. When I select any element from first drop down then second drop down is opening through the code but when I try this on Simulator/Device wrapping the same code using XCODE then second drop down is getting focused only. It is not opening as it is working in browser.